# Transforme string code to font awesome to unicode Android

Tags: java, android, font-awesome

I am using `font awesome` to show icons in a generate a bottom menu.I receive from server just the correspondent code like f021,

I've tried use an escape like `\\u` .

```
    String icon = "\\u"+ feature.getIcon();
    textIcon.setText(icon);
```

I would like to transform in unicode and use `textview.settext("my unicode")`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's is the solution that I was looking for:

```
    long valLong = Long.parseLong(valueUnicodeStr, 16);
    textIcon.setText(String.format("%s", (char) valLong));
```

Comment: Does solve the task, thank you. But the first two lines of your example are senseless.